# Extracting multiple words from pandas dataframe column into same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-structures, split

Suppose a dataframe consists of two columns A={1,2,3} B={'a b c d', 'e f g h', 'i j k l'}. For A = 2, I would like to change the corresponding entry in column B to 'e f h'. (ie. extract the first, second and last word, not drop the third word, not the same).

It is easy to extract single words using the df.loc[df['colA']=2,'colB'].str.split().str[x], where x= 0,1 and -1, but I'm having difficulty joining the three words back into one string efficiently. The most efficient way I can think of is provided below. Is there a better way of achieving what I'm trying to do? Thanks.

```
y = lambda x : df.loc[df['colA']==2,'colB'].str.split().str[x]
df.loc[df['colA']=2,'colB'] = y(0) + ' ' + y(1) + ' ' + y(-1)
```

Expected and actual result:

```
A     B
1  a b c d
2  e f h
3  i j k l
```

Comment: How are you deciding what gets extracted?  Is it by position or by some regex?

Comment: The cell value is split by default by space. But I need to extract the first, second and last word. To choose the which row to extract words from is dependent on a static value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close to the solution, the only problem is that `str[x]` returns a value wrapped in a [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.html) object. You could fix this by extracting the value from the Series as shown:

```
y = lambda x : df.loc[df['colA']==2,'colB'].str.split().str[x].values[0]
df.loc[df['colA']==2,'colB'] = y(0) + ' ' + y(1) + ' ' + y(-1)
```

You can also achieve the same by making use of the apply function

```
df.loc[df['colA']==2, 'colB'] = df.loc[df['colA']==2,'colB'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.split()[0:2] + [x.split()[-1]]))
```

Comment: That one liner is what I was after. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A': [1,2,3], 
                          'B': ['a b c d', 'e f g h', 'i j k l']})

y = lambda x : df.loc[df['A']==2,'B'].str[0:2*x+2] + df.loc[df['A']==2,'B'].str[-1]
df.loc[df1['A']==2,'B'] = y(1)
```

Then `df` is the wanted:

```
   A        B
0  1  a b c d
1  2    e f h
2  3  i j k l
```

Comment: Of course this works for letters. if you have words as you say in your comments, then you indeed have to split

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case I have words, but for letters your code would work. Cheers.